# Changing Xscreensaver's Video Player from mpv to VLC

Tags: command-line, video, vlc, screensaver, xscreensaver

The [official documentation for xscreensaver](https://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html#mpeg) gives an example of how to play videos as a screensaver:

> Install mpv and add something like the following to the `programs' preference in your .xscreensaver file:

```
 "My Movie"  mpv --really-quiet --no-audio --fs --loop=inf  \
                 --no-stop-screensaver                      \
                 --wid=$XSCREENSAVER_WINDOW                 \
                 $HOME/movies/*.mp4                       \n\
```

That's all well and good, but I would love to have one less dependency on my system (namely, mpv). I'd like to do the same thing, but with VLC.

I've tried adding this to my .xscreensaver file:

```
"My Movie"  vlc -L -R -f --intf dummy --no-video-title-show  \
                        $HOME/movies/*.mp4                 \n\
```

This command works perfectly on the command line, but when launched via xscreensaver, this happens:

[image: Sorry for the blurrycam, I couldn't take a screenshot without exiting the screensaver!]
<sup><sup>Sorry for the blurrycam, I couldn't take a screenshot without exiting the screensaver!</sup></sup>

What do you mean, `unknown option or missing mandatory argument '--intf'`?! It's right there!

Does anyone know why I can't get this VLC command to run via xscreensaver, when it works perfectly when launched straight-up on the command line?

Comment: what happens if you execute the vlc command from the terminal? Do you still see this error? If yes try to reinstall VLC

Comment: No, it works just fine in the terminal. Same exact command. That's what I said in the last sentence in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this work for me :D

```
"Videos"    cvlc --loop --fullscreen --drawable-xid   \
              $XSCREENSAVER_WINDOW                    \
              --no-video-title-show                   \
              /path/to/videos.mp4                     \n\
```

Comment: I'm surprised by the CPU usage. `mpv` uses around 40% of my cpu to drive the screensaver on two displays, whereas `cvlc` peaks my CPU to 100% and spins up my fans.

Comment: Correction: My CPU seems to spike to 100% using `clvc`, but then calms down to around 40% after about 5 seconds. Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using VLC on xscreensaver for almost a year now. The solution posted here didn't seem to work for me without further tweaking. For anyone coming here on a search engine like I did, an alternate solution that works with VLC version 3.0.12 on Ubuntu (Lubuntu) 21.04:

```
"Pirate Cinema"  cvlc --loop -Z --fullscreen     \
      --ignore-config --video-filter "vhs"        \
      --no-interact --no-disable-screensaver      \
      --drawable-xid $XSCREENSAVER_WINDOW         \
      --no-audio "$HOME/Videos"      \n\
```

Photo of two monitors with the xscreensaver lock screen visible above two different videos:

[image: photo]